# How to know the pointer to the instance that fired events

Tags: c#, events

How can I know the pointer to the instance that fired events? I used "object sender" as the event's first parameter and I cast it. but there is not any properties like "Tag" that help me to distinguish different components.

here is my sample code :

```
SMSCclientSMPP[] smsCClientSMPP = new SMSCclientSMPP[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    smsCClientSMPP[i] = new SMSCclientSMPP();
    smsCClientSMPP[i].OnTcpDisconnected += smsCclientSMPP_OnTcpDisconnected;
}
private void smsCclientSMPP_OnTcpDisconnected(object sender, tcpDisconnectedEventArgs e)
{
    SMSCclientSMPP obj = (SMSCclientSMPP)sender;
    // obj dosent have Tag field.
}
```

as I said, `obj` dosent have any properties that makes it different from others.
so how can I know this event is fired by which items of my `smsCClientSMPP` array.
Thanks for any helping...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, nor if this actually answers your question, but since each item is a different instance, they should have a different [`GetHashCode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value:

```
obj.GetHashCode()
```

Comment: dose GetHashCode() have different value for different instance surely? dose it have same value every time that its event fire?

Comment: Why do you need to know what object raised an event?

Comment: @Elahe It depends on the implementation of `SMSCclientSMPP`. You can read the documentation in the link I provided and check whether the method is overriden in the class using a decompiler.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about SMSCclientSMPP, but the easiest way to achieve it would be to wrap SMSCclientSMPP creating a custom class with new property Tag or ID to identify those objects.

Everything else should stay the same, you'd just replace SMSCclientSMPP with your new class. Of course that will only work if SMSCclientSMPP can be inherited.